# What are the two blisters on F-35 upper wing surface?

Tags: feature-identification, f-35

For all of the F-35 models you can find pictures with and without a blister on the upper wing surface. I'm guessing that it is sensors for the missile warning system that were retrofitted later on, but I couldn't find any information supporting that.
[image: F-35B without blisters]
[image: F-35B with blisters]
[image: F-35A without blisters]
[image: F-35A with blisters]
[image: F-35C without blisters]
[image: F-35C with blisters]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are Luneberg Reflectors.

They enhance the radar cross section of the aircraft.

For two reasons; to be more safe around civilian traffic due to being easier spotted by traffic control radars, and where they do not want adversaries to train their radar systems on it to gain knowledge of its strengths and weaknesses.

Not sure if those on the picture is retractable, or has to be fitted/removed by mechanics.

There are many sources for this, here is one:
https://www.businessinsider.com/f-35-luneberg-radar-cross-section-russia-estonia-2017-5?r=US&IR=T

Comment: Do you maybe have a source for that? The positioning seems counterintuitive to me since the F-22 places its Luneberg Reflector on the belly of the aircraft where it is well in the line of sight for ground based radar, while I guess the ones on the F-35 would be quit well hidden from ground based radar.

Comment: added a random source

Comment: @hph304j There is one on the underside as well

Comment: Nice find and +1, but how does it make it more safe around civilian planes? Civilian planes typically use TCAS which won't be affected by those reflectors.

Comment: edited to answer that better

Comment: @ymb1: I don't know where you get the idea that civilian planes typically use TCAS.  Commercial airliners may, but those are only a fraction of the civilian aircraft out there.  If you're flying your Cessna 172, Piper Cherokee, or whatever, especially around the western US where there's a lot of military training, it's rather nice if ATC can see those jets.

Comment: @jamesqf: Right. That is if those civilian ATC units rely on PSR (which, without altitude data, isn't really good when the target is a highly maneuverable jet). My request for clarification is clear and on point; taking it out of context is something else. (Point being, that F-35 probably has its transponder on for the ATC units and TCAS equipped aircraft.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, they’re radar reflectors used during peacetime operations.  They are removed prior to combat flight ops.